# Why does UILocalNotification with region not fire?

Tags: objective-c, core-location, uilocalnotification, ios8

I have followed the example given in the [WWDC 2014 session "What's New in iOS Notifications"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?include=713#713) to set up a [`UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/region) delivery when a region's boundary is crossed.

However, my notification never fires on device nor simulator running iOS beta 3. The notification works fine when I tested using a `fireDate` instead of a `region` (not both at same time-- that's not allowed).

I have set `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in my `Info.plist`.

Here is my Obj-C code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *notifLocation;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // test points at Apple HQ
    self.notifLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:37.331741 longitude:-122.030333];

    [self setupLocationMonitoring];
}

- (void) setupLocationMonitoring
{
    if (self.locationManager == nil) {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    }

    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10; // meters

    // iOS 8+ request authorization to track the user’s location
    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)registerLocationNotification
{
    UILocalNotification *locNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    locNotification.alertBody = @"Hello!";

    // doesn't work
    locNotification.regionTriggersOnce = NO;
    locNotification.region = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:self.notifLocation.coordinate radius:50 identifier:@"PlaceName"];

    // works:
//    locNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];

    UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [application cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    [application scheduleLocalNotification:locNotification];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
    // check status to see if we’re authorized
    BOOL canUseLocationNotifications = (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse);
    if (canUseLocationNotifications) {
        [self registerLocationNotification];
    }
}

@end
```

Note: this question is about iOS 8's new Location Notifications, not about region monitoring on older versions of iOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works fine for me. Here are the steps on `iPhone Simulator`:

1) Open Simulator app and choose the following option from the top menu `Debug` -> `Location` -> `Custom Location` and put there the coordinates as you have in code: (37.331741, -122.030333)

2) Run your Xcode project on `iPhone Simulator`

3) Background the app

4) Open the same top menu item `Debug` -> `Location` but change it from `Custom Location` to `Freeway Drive` or `City Run`. Play with `City Run`/ `Freeway Drive` and `Custom Location`

I see the notification when I follow these steps. Looks like it doesn't work in case appropriate coordinate is a starting one but it works when the coordinate changes to appropriate from some others.

Comment: Thank you for the procedure with the simulator. For some reason, my original simulator procedure was not getting the notification to pop up.